# How can I use UIProgressView to show the NSData write and read in ios?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nstimer, nsthread, uiprogressview

As title, I want to know the progress of NSData write or read in the iOS device, use the UIProgressView to show it, use `NSThread` to write data and use `NSTimer` to check file size, but I have not been successful.

How can I do it?

```
- (void)load:(long)section {
    //set Timer
    float theInterval = 0.01f;

    copyFileTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:theInterval target:self selector:@selector(progressFile) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];        
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(writeFile:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void) writeFile:(id)sender {
    [movieData writeToFile:moviePath atomically:YES];
}

- (void)progressFile {
    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:moviePath error:nil];
    NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
    NSInteger fileSize = [fileSizeNumber integerValue];

    [self updateProgress:(float)fileSize / (float)size];
    currentPer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%%", (float)fileSize / (float)size * 100];
    if ((float)fileSize / (float)size == 1) {
        [copyFileTimer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a minimal example of the code you have tried so far?

Comment: @AndrewMorton
Ok, fine.